# Wordpress/Woocommerce: External JS loading, but not working. 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to PHP and wordpress/woocommerce, so I apologize if the answer is obvious, but I've been through many of the questions similar to this to no avail.

I wrote some very basic JS:

```
1. window.onload = function viewcart(){
2.   document.querySelectorAll('.added_to_cart').innerHTML="ca";
3.  //  document.querySelector('a.added_to_cart.wc-forward:before').innerHTML="ca";
4. //  document.getElementsByClassName('.wc-forward::after').innerHTML="ca";
5. }
```

I #'ed the lines here to better reference. Lines 3-4 are examples of different ways I have tried to solve this issue.

Here is another example:

```
function viewcart(){
var a= document.querySelector('.added_to_cart.wc-forward');
a.innerHTML="#";
}
```

**SOMETIMES** the '**Cannot set property 'innerHTML**' of null' message does **NOT** appear.

***But* even if there is no error in element inspector, the JS is still not applying either way**

(even though the error message appears, proving the external js sheet is being gathered).

Here are the steps I took:

1. Loaded the js to my Wordpress (using **CHILD** theme) by adding the external js sheet (viewcart.js) to the child theme file w/STFP.
2. Added the following to CHILD theme's functions.php:

   ```
    <?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_scripts' );

   function child_add_scripts() {
   wp_register_script(
   'viewcartscript',
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/viewcart.js',
   true,
   false
   );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'viewcartscript' );
   }
   ?>
   ```

3.Tried editing true --> false, false --> true. Removed one 'true', removed one 'false'.

The div I am trying to change features before:: and after:: css, and also makes reference to an external stylesheet. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Here is a link to my website (I am still working on it haha so please excuse the lack of domain etc. I cannot apologize for any kitten photos though!): http://woocommerce-8778-19565-47619.cloudwaysapps.com/product-category/jewelry#

Thank you in advance for ANY help! :)

Comment: I think your problem here is that there are no `.added_to_cart` links when the `onload` function fires. The `.added_to_cart` links are added dynamically to the page _after_ a user clicks on the add-to-cart button. You can't target an element `onload` that isn't already part of the DOM tree.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you so much for your help! I was also thinking this could be an issue, do you have any suggestions on what to look into in order to make this happen? Thanks again xx